# Problems executing Bibtex in Texmaker with multibib package

Tags: bibtex, texmaker, multibib

I'm new to multibib. I know I should run bibtex for each defined bibliography, but I can't find how. I work in Texmaker. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{P}{Math Readings}
\newcites{R}{Physics Readings}

\begin{document}

An interesting citation is \citeP{GKS}. See also \citeR{L}.

\bibliographystyleP{unsrt}
\bibliographyP{bibliographyP}

\bibliographystyleR{unsrt}
\bibliographyR{bibliographyR}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You can format your code block by highlighting it with your mouse, then clicking on the `{}` icon above the question box.  (I could edit it, but then my name rather than yours would appear on the question.)